# Problema con variable en C, ¿qué hice mal?

Tags: c

aquí un novato en C. Estoy con unas tareas de algoritmos en el IDE Zinjai, no me muestra la variable 'total' que hice mal?

Enunciado:

Una tienda ofrece un descuento del 15% sobre el total de la compra y un cliente desea saber cuanto deberá pagar finalmente por su compra.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        
    float desc, total, pagof;
    
    desc= total*0.15;
        
    printf("Ingresa total de compra\n");
    scanf("%f", &total);
        
    printf("El total a pagar es: $\n", total-desc);
    printf("El descuento aplicado es: ", desc);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Estás "intentando" calcular el descuento sin ni siquiera haber leído el total de la compra. Mueve el cálculo del descuento hacia abajo. Finalmente agrega el formato de salida en los `printf` para imprimir las variables correctamente. Tu código quedaría:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float desc, total, pagof;

    printf("Ingresa total de compra\n");
    scanf("%f", &total);
    desc = total * 0.15;

    printf("El total a pagar es: $%.2f\n", total - desc);
    printf("El descuento aplicado es: %.2f", desc);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @MarcTillo si esta respuesta te sirivio, recuerda aceptarla!

Answer (score 0):

¡Saludos!

*Primero tienes que leer el dato del total introducido por el usuario
*Segundo tienes que realizar la operación de descuento
*Tercero mandas a imprimir el descuento sin olvidar el formato de retorno en tu caso %f, para ver el resultado acotando dos decimales sería %.2f

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main () {       
  float desc, total, pagof;
    
  printf("Ingresa total de compra\n");
  scanf("%f", &total);

  desc= total*0.15; 
   
  printf("El total a pagar es: $%.2f\n", total-desc);
  printf("El descuento aplicado es: $%.2f", desc);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola!!! podrias contarme en que se diferencia esta respuesta con la otra, que es exactamente igual?